# ¡Conozcan a nuestro tercer moderador: Miquel Coll!

Tags: discusión, moderadores

Nos hemos dado cuenta que el crecimiento de nuestra comunidad ha creado dificultades para Luiggi y para mi siendo los únicos moderadores del sitio.  Hemos hablado en varias ocasiones sobre la ayuda que nos proporcionaría un moderador más.  Al hablar sobre las cualidades necesarias para un candidato a esta posición, nos dimos cuenta que había ciertas cosas que no podían faltar. Buscábamos a alguien en Europa, a alguien con entusiasmo y carisma, y lo más importante, alguien cuyo deseo fuera el motivar y educar a nuestros nuevos usuarios sin disminuir la importancia de nuestros usuarios establecidos.

Me gustaría presentarles a nuestro tercer moderador: [Miquel Coll](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7242/miquel-coll).

[image: Miquel Coll]

Les dejo un poco sobre él para que lo vayan conociendo mejor:

> ### Miquel Coll es:
>
> Soy un chico de Barcelona (y un poco culé) amante de la música y la informática des de pequeño y que ha tenido la suerte de dedicarse profesionalmente en ambas cosas de manera paralela.
>
> Aún recuerdo, con 8-9 años, coger el portátil de mi padre y a base de prueba y error conseguir abrir los pocos juegos que había en esa época (especialmente el prince of persia) - con un MS DOS puro y duro sin nada gráfico. (aprender a base de error qué hace cd, ., tabulador, dir, etc... ¡imaginaos!).
>
> Ya de más grandullón, con 15 años programé mi primer programa, y cómo no podía ser de otra manera, con temática musical. Se trataba de reproducir de las más bajas frecuencias a las más altas para ver cómo era el estado del oído de quién lo utilizaba sin tener ningún tipo de altavoz - generaba los sonidos con el propio hardware del ordenador en QBasic (¡Cuánto pantallazo azul que he visto en mi vida!).
>
> Poco después, con visual basic y QBasic, programé bastantes programas que me dejaron una cosa clara: Me gustaba hacer esto.
>
> Y de ahí directo a la FIB - soy un FIBer - la Facultad de informática de Barcelona dónde me gradué como ingeniero informático.
>
> Entre la universidad y hoy he trabajado con iOS, Android, PhoneGap y realizado tareas de Data Mining pero ya hace unos años que me encontré con el mundo .NET y de ahí ya.... WCF, WebForms, WinForms, MVC, combinado con HTML, CSS, Javascript/JQuery, etc... y con muchas plataformas distintas combinado siempre que puedo con SCRUM/Kanban en mis proyectos (soy un gran fan de SCRUM, sí) y ahí sigo actualmente.
>
> Tengo mucha ilusión y ganas para empezar este nuevo reto, les agradezco mucho a Juan y Luiggi su apoyo y estoy convencido que voy a aprender mucho de ellos y de la comunidad dónde me uní hace bastante menos que muchos pero que he seguido de manera constante des de que vi que existía.
>
> Voy a aprender de mis errores (no dudéis de que pronto los habrá) y siempre de manera positiva; si veis algo raro, ping en el chat y ahí estaré :).
>
> Os animo a continuar preguntando, respondiendo y en gran medida ayudar a los nuevos usuarios.
>
> ¡Nos vemos por el sitio!

¡Ayúdenme a darle una gran bienvenida a Miquel!

Comment: ¿¿FIBer?? Yo soy teleco, de la ETSETB... lo cual como sabrás nos obliga a ser enemigos mortales. Será divertido, ¡bienvenido!

Comment: Muchas felicidades!!! señor diamante

Comment: @Konamiman ahora nos llevamos bien! haha Gracias :)

Comment: La verdad es que el nombre me suena... es que Barcelona es diminuta :)

Comment: Enhorabuena, Miquel

Comment: ¡Muchas felicidades!

Comment: De lo que nos perdemos algunos, felicidades @MiquelColl !! :-P

Comment: ¿por qué lo buscaban en Europa?

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer para que los que tenemos horario europeo tengamos atención del moderador durante la mañana (horario europeo) que es la noche en el otro lado del charco :)

Comment: Genial. Pues bien. Felicitaciones, entonces

Comment: Felicidades @MiquelColl

Answer (score 10):

[image: Me alegro un montón. Por vos y por todos nosotros]

¡Felicitaciones!

---

Y qué bueno Juan, que en la elección no hayan dejado de lado:

> sin disminuir la importancia de nuestros usuarios establecidos

Comment: Claro.  ¡Nuestros usuarios establecidos son de suma importancia!

Comment: ¡Gracias Mariano! Todos somos importantes en la comunidad :)

Comment: ¿Qué es un `"usuario establecido"`?

Comment: @PaulVargas Un usuario establecido es alguien que a participado en el sitio al comentar, votar, preguntar, o responder en varias ocasiones.  Es una persona que usa el sitio y tiene interacciones con otros miembros regularmente.

Answer (score 5):

Muchas felicidades Miquel, espero que tengas éxito en tu encomienda, por el bien común.

Comment: Muchas gracias toledano. Se aprecian mucho siempre tus aportaciones en la comunidad y de seguro que entre todos vamos a mejor :)

Answer (score 4):

Es grato ver el crecimiento que ha tenido la comunidad. Felicitaciones Miquel Coll por hacer parte de ello!!! :D

Comment: ¡Gracias Goerman! Efectivamente la comunidad está creciendo, a seguir empujando.

Answer (score 3):

bienvenido hermano! las mejores de las vibras, muchos éxitos y a seguir creciendo con toda la comunidad hispana (y los que vengan de otros países a colaborar en el sitio :D) de desarrolladores de software y tecnologías de la información!

*Venga, vamos con todo el power 2.0!*

Comment: Felicitaciones Miguel Coll, exitos!!!

Comment: @PedroÁvila Es Miquel, no Miguel, jeje.

Comment: @ArtEze No vaya a ser que conteste como en la película *Lord of War*: "Prefiero a mi manera".

Comment: Gracias :) Seguro que todos juntos conseguiremos que esta sea una comunidad de referencia.

Comment: Así es como dice @PaulVargas "prefiero a mi manera", jajajaja.... es una broma

Answer (score 3):

WEEEE!! Felicidades Miquel :D Seguro que te va fenomenal :D

Comment: ¡Las nuevas generaciones van fuertes! Gracias Dianne, mi compañera española en el chat haha

Answer (score 3):

Ya te lo había comentado de antemano en un chat privado, pero ahora lo hago público.

Primero que nada, felicitaciones por ser el nuevo moderador, JuanM ya lo tenía pensado y me consultó quién podría ayudar en el sitio, mi opinión fue que tú podrías ayudar bastante por la misma participación que vi de tu parte, tus reportes y sobretodo tus energías para ayudar a la comunidad tanto a los usuarios como a mantener las publicaciones limpias.

Segundo, te pido tener mucha paciencia antes de actuar. Habrán publicaciones que te parezca que deban ser eliminadas de la faz de la tierra, pero hay que pensarlo dos veces antes de aplicar el [ban hammer](http://darkzonereport.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Ban-Hammer-Banner-800x445.jpg).

Tercero, somos un equipo de moderadores, estamos para apoyarnos junto con JuanM y los futuros moderadores. Habrán publicaciones donde quizás no sepas que hacer, me ha pasado, podemos conversar al respecto y llegar a un consenso.

Sé que la diferencia de zonas horarias (tú en España, yo en Perú), los horarios de oficina, las actividades de la vida personal, etc puede complicar un poco la comunicación, pero no dejemos que sea una limitante, encontraremos alguna manera de estar sincronizados y comunicados.

Buenas vibras, mucho entusiasmo y a seguir hacia adelante por la comunidad.

Comment: De nuevo, agradezco mucho la confianza y oportunidad. Sin duda alguna voy a aprender mucho del trabajo que ya has realizado siempre pensando en la comunidad. Ahora que veo todo el trabajo realizado, *chapeau*

Answer (score 3):

Felicitats company! Fes el bé allà on vagis!

Comment: [Relacionado](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fya6qrComsU) :D ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Mis respetos, no es fácil graduarse de ingeniero informático.

Comment: No es fácil pero se aprende muchísimo y uno sale muy preparado :)

Answer (score 2):

Felicidades Señor, que bueno que la comunidad vaya creciendo. Abrazos y éxitos en esta tarea.

Comment: :D ¡Muchas gracias Alan!

Answer (score 1):

¡¡¡¡ Enhorabuena @Miquel Coll !!!!!

Espero que la comunidad siga creciendo!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

P.D.: Yo soy otro Ingeniero Informático que se suma a esta comunidad