# ¡Ayúdenme a dar la bienvenida a nuestros nuevos moderadores Pro Tempore - ArtEze y FredyFx!

Tags: discusión, moderadores

[LuiggiMendoza](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/519/conozcan-a-nuestro-segundo-moderador-luiggi-mendoza) y [MiquelColl](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/888/conozcan-a-nuestro-tercer-moderador-miquel-coll) han ayudado tremendamente a dirigir a nuestra comunidad al moderar nuestro sitio pero últimamente, ambos han necesitado alejarse un tiempo por motivos personales. Esto nos ha dejado con un vacío que no se puede ignorar.

Los moderadores son y seguirán siendo voluntarios y miembros de la comunidad quienes mantienen las reglas, las preguntas y respuestas, y las interacciones entre miembros de nuestro sitio en buena orden.  El ser moderador significa que la persona es digna de confianza y durante nuestro tiempo como sitio Beta, es necesario el tener moderadores como ellos.

He tenido el placer de conocer a [ArtEze](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/13558/arteze) y a [FredyFx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/822/fredyfx) y respeto a los dos por su conocimiento sobre el desarrollo y también como personas que quieren que nuestra comunidad crezca lo más saludable posible. He sido testigo de como ambos han ayudado a varios nuevos usuarios en la sala de chat y he visto a los dos ser apreciados por sus contribuciones y aportaciones en el sitio principal.

Dado a nuestras circunstancias, les pedí a estos muchachos si les interesaría ayudarnos durante este tiempo, hasta llegar a nuestras propias elecciones las cuales planeo tener a finales de junio. Ambos aceptaron el reto y empezarán como moderadores hechos y derechos desde ahorita mismo. En cuanto tengamos nuestras elecciones, serán removidos al igual que LuiggiMendoza y MiquelColl.  Si les interesa ingresarse a las postulaciones, se le permitirá también pero la comunidad votará por los 3 moderadores oficiales de nuestra comunidad.

En fin, les he pedido a [ArtEze](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/13558/arteze) y a [FredyFx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/822/fredyfx) que me compartan una corta biografía para que los puedan conocer mejor.  En cuanto las tenga, actualizo esta publicación para mostrárselas. Pero mientras esperamos, ¡ayúdenme a felicitarlos y darles la bienvenida!

[image: fredyfx]

> Hola buenas madrugadas, mi nombre es Fredy Guibert a.k.a fredyfx y
> aquí le vamos siempre Con todo el power 2.0! Me encantan tanto las
> tecnologías Microsoft que inicié una comunidad académica llamada
> "UPAO.net" en el 2008 cuando estaba en 1er ciclo de la universidad con
> el apoyo de mis amigos, desde la creación de la comunidad siempre
> hemos estado activos y se mantiene con vida de manera consecutiva año
> tras año gracias a sus integrantes que comparten las mismas ganas de
> "aprender para compartir" lema que tenemos instalado en el C:\orazón y
> en el C:\erebro :D
>
> Me gustó tanto la forma de vivir entre comunidades
> tanto presenciales como online que ahora me encuentran seguido por
> estos lares de StackOverflow con la misma vibración: aprendiendo y
> compartiendo con una sonrisa enorme :D Daré lo mejor de mi para que la
> hermandad de SOes siga elevando el cosmos! Vamos con todo el power
> 2.0!

[image: ArtEze]

> Yo soy Emiliano Ezequiel Parenti, me llaman por mi segundo nombre,
> Ezequiel, soy argentino, en mi infancia conocí al amigo de mi padre,
> Gustavo (el gusi), y él fue quien me  regaló el 3D Studio Max, y un
> libro de modelaje 3D. Me pareció divertido y me hice fanático de la
> informática. Ya más tarde, en la escuela, me empezó a gustar la
> matemática.
>
> Cuando tenía 13 años tuve un amigo llamado JH (José Hernaldo), y con
> él aprendí a programar en Javascript, cosa que me parece muy útil. Ya
> de grande, ahora tengo 23 años, y hace algunos años en la UTN
> (Universidad Tecnológica Nacional) tuve un profe llamado Pablo
> Sznajdleder, si quieren [pasen por su blog](http://holamundoc.blogspot.com.ar/), que nos enseñó C y C++, y creo
> que son unos de los lenguajes más importantes.

Comment: Muy contento por la noticia!!

Comment: Genial! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GwjfUFyY6M

Comment: Enhorabuena a los dos!!

Comment: muchas gracias por la confianza y la oportunidad :D ahí le vamos! Con todo el power 2.0! :D

Comment: Con **Todo el power 2.0** @fredyfx

Comment: Muchas gracias a LuggiMendoza y MiquelColl por el tiempo que sirvieron como moderadores pro tempore.

Comment: @Rubén seguimos siendo moderadores. Yo sigo apoyando a la comunidad. Fredy y Art son un refuerzo ;)

Comment: @fredyfx felicidades hermanito!

Comment: @ArtEze grande crack! felicidades!

Comment: @JuanM los anteriores moderadores ¿continuan siendo moderadores?

Comment: @Jorgesys lo responde luiggi unos comentarios antes ;)

Comment: @EmanuelVe gracias, ya veo ⤜(ʘ_ʘ)⤏

Comment: gracias hermano @EmanuelVe :D

Comment: felicitaciones a los nuevos moderadores

Comment: Felicidades!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @EmanuelVe ¡Jeje, gracias! Un honor.

Comment: Enhorabuena a ambos.! :D

Answer (score 17):

Felicidades!

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Dos muy buenas y capaces personas para ayudar al sitio con el **Power 2.0**

---

Asi que a celebrar!

- Kool & The Gang -  Celebration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GwjfUFyY6M
- Kool & The Gang - Get Down On It: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qchPLaiKocI

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: usemos esta respuesta para añadir comentarios :)

Comment: Wow, me alegra mucho la noticia, fredyfx y arteze tienen todo mi apoyo :D ¡¡¡Felicidades!!!!

Comment: gracias hermanos :D seguiré colaborando con todo el power 2.0!!!

Comment: (⌐■_■) @fredyfx felicidades hermano! También a ti amigo ArtEze , saludos!

Comment: ᕦ ´• ᴥ •` ᕥ Felicidades @ArtEze buenas opciones para Moderator!

Comment: Está genial ser moderador, gracias @Jorgesys

Comment: @Flxtr y a tí también, gracias.

Comment: Muchas felicidades ArtEze y fredyfx

Comment: @fredyfx y ArtEze mi felicidades mis hermano sigan asi :D

Answer (score 9):

Felicito y deseo el mayor de los aciertos a ArtEze y fredyfx.

Aprovecho para dar las **gracias a Luiggi y Miquel por su dedicación, esfuerzo y generosidad**. Especialmente a Luiggi, que en largas temporadas ha sido el único moderador. Seguro que es duro tener tal responsabilidad de forma voluntaria en un sitio que es ya de los más grandes de Stack Exchange.

Un moderador suele moverse silenciosamente y su trabaja pasa prácticamente inadvertido. Eso sí, es mucho lo que se hace y estoy seguro de que en Stack Overflow en español estamos en el orden de los miles de reportes gestionados, por no mencionar otras acciones de moderador (gestión de usuarios, de etiquetas, spam...).

Con la graduación se perderán temporalmente muchos privilegios de moderación, así que a buen seguro los nuevos moderadores tendrán mucha faena. ¡Ayudémosles!

Comment: Gracias... Sí, anda por ahí la cifra.

Comment: gracias bro! :D

Answer (score 7):

Este es un cambio de rumbo en la dirección apropiada.
Felicidades por una muy acertada decisión, Juan M.

Felicidades a los dos nuevos moderadores.

Y felicidades sobre todo a la comunidad, que es quien más sale ganando con estos nombramientos.

Comment: ahí vamos con lo mejor que podamos :D

Answer (score 6):

¡¡¡Muchísimas felicitaciones ArtEze y fredyfx!!!
-y qué mejor momento que la graduación para arrancar con todo el power 2.0.

Estar al día con los reportes es algo que se estaba tornando más que necesario y veo con muy buenos ojos que se sumen más personas a la tarea.

Uno de los puntos más complicados de entender en la moderación es cómo determinar bajo qué característica cae el contenido de las publicaciones: qué significa "*baja calidad*", qué significa realmente "*se ve bien*", o qué "*no es una respuesta*", entre otros. Es difícil comprenderlo y lleva tiempo. Y muchos de los reportes enviados están actualmente siendo limpiados o anulados por otras acciones posteriores, sin que el usuario que envió el reporte tenga un feedback para poder entender qué acción es la correcta.

Creo que tener una moderación más activa va a ayudar positivamente a que el sitio crezca de forma sana.

Comment: Sí, es costoso de entender, creo que con la práctica uno aprende a discernir las publicaciones. Agradezco el recibimiento.

Comment: @ArtEze y sobre todo es algo que me parece que sería bueno que los nuevos usuarios aprendan, viendo el resultado de los reportes que envían... Actualmente no estaban teniendo respuesta de un moderador... Enseñarle a los nuevos usuarios de esta forma haría que todo funcione mejor

Comment: De hecho también son muy útiles las publicaciones en que la gente pregunta por qué un caso concreto se resolvió así o así. Da la oportunidad a los moderadores de expresar sus puntos de vista, que la gente los conozco y, si se da el caso, se debatan.

Answer (score 6):

Saludos y muchas facilidades a ambos.

Comment: ¿no será *felicidades*? :P

Comment: ¿Insinúas que los moderadores merecen más felicidad que facilidad?

Comment: Por supuesto, la felicidad es la clave del éxito :D

Comment: Difícilmente van a ser felices si no les facilitamos su trabajo ;)

Comment: [_@CriticalGhost A no ser que no quieras facilidades en tu día O_o_](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36804120#36804120)

Answer (score 5):

### Felicidades @ArtEze y @FredyFx!!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

P.D.: Y cómo no, dar las gracias también a @LuiggiMendoza y @MiquelColl por su dedicación y esfuerzo.

Comment: Gracias! justo lo leí con la voz de Homero hahaha!

Answer (score 2):

Felicidades Chicos, Saludos para ambos y que lo paseis muy bien :D a tope de POWER!!!!, yo invito el cafecito XD

Comment: queda! gracias bro :D

Comment: :3 jejejeje XD de nada men