# Histórico de moderadores de SOes

Tags: discusión, moderadores

Durante el tiempo, Stack Overflow en español ha tenido distintos moderadores. Unos fueron elegidos inicialmente, luego salieron y fueron cubiertos por otros.

¿Cuál ha sido la evolución de moderadores en este sitio?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### 15 dic 2015 → [15 de diciembre 2015: Se abre Stack Overflow en español al público](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258/83)

---

#### 17 dic 2015

- Entra (Pro Tem) [Konamiman](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/23/konamiman) <sub>[¡Conozcan a nuestro primer moderador: Konamiman!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276/83)</sub>

Equipo completo:

[image]

#### 23 marzo 2016

- Entra (Pro Tem) un moderador que se desasoció del sitio (Mod2)

Equipo completo:

[image]
Mod2

#### 23 marzo 2016

- Entra (Pro Tem) Miquel Coll <sub>[¡Conozcan a nuestro tercer moderador: Miquel Coll!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/888/83)</sub>

Equipo completo:

[image]
Mod2
[image]

#### 1 abril 2016

- Sale Konamiman <sub>al convertirse en empleado de Stack Overflow</sub>

Equipo completo:

Mod2
[image]

#### 16 mayo 2017

- Entra (Pro Tem) ArtEze <sub>[¡Ayúdenme a dar la bienvenida a nuestros nuevos moderadores Pro Tempore - ArtEze y FredyFx!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1970/83)</sub>
- Entra (Pro Tem) fredyfx <sub>[¡Ayúdenme a dar la bienvenida a nuestros nuevos moderadores Pro Tempore - ArtEze y FredyFx!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1970/83)</sub>
- Sale Mod2
- Sale Miquel Coll

Equipo completo:

[image]
[image]

---

#### 17 mayo 2017 → [¡Stack Overflow en español se gradúa hoy!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/17/stack-overflow-en-espanol-se-gradua-hoy/)

---

#### 1 agosto 2017 [Elección de Moderador de 2017](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1) → [¡Felicidades a nuestros 3 moderadores oficiales!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/08/01/felicidades-nuestros-3-moderadores-oficiales/)

- Alvaro Montoro <sub>[Demos la bienvenida a nuestros 3 moderadores oficiales](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2614/83)</sub>
- Jorgesys <sub>[Demos la bienvenida a nuestros 3 moderadores oficiales](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2614/83)</sub>
- lois6b <sub>[Demos la bienvenida a nuestros 3 moderadores oficiales](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2614/83)</sub>

Equipo completo:

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### 31 enero 2018

- Entre g3rv4 <sub>[Tenemos un nuevo moderador: g3rv4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3111/83)</sub>

Equipo completo:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### 2 abril 2019

- Sale g3rv4 <sub>[No soy más moderador de SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3112/83)</sub>

Equipo completo:

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### 9 abril 2019 [Elección de Moderador de 2019](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/2) → [Resultados de la elección de moderadores, 2019](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4050/83)

- Entra gbianchi
- Entra Pikoh

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### 23 enero 2020

- Sale lois6b <sub>[Dejo mi puesto de moderador diamantado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4549/)</sub>

Equipo completo:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: no sabia que el chico de las historietas fue nuestro primer mod!

Comment: ¡Gracias @Konamiman ! No supe encontrar ninguna publicación donde se anunciara tu fichaje por la empresa.

Comment: Lo dije en el chat en su día, pero aparte de eso no se publicó, cierto.

Comment: ¿Sería recomendable respetar el deseo de quien disoció su nombre de este sitio y no incluir su nombre aquí? Con decir que un moderador anónimo, o algo similar, fue el segundo se cumple tanto el propósito de esta respuesta como el deseo de ese moderador.

Comment: @JoseAntonio buena pregunta. No sé si su intención fue de borrar la vinculación de su nombre con el sitio, pues hay unas cuantas preguntas de Meta con su nombre completo (como la que indico al nombrarlo) que no fueron tocadas. Si quieres modificarlo, adelante

Comment: @fedorqui Pues ya está. Luego pensé en editar la página de bienvenida pero mejor ser prudente. Me he limitado a quitar el enlace. Eso ya para otro momento. Y después de hablarlo.