# ¿Por qué jachguate no fue el gestor de la comunidad?

Tags: discusión, moderadores, area51

Si el que propuso el sitio fue [jachguate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/21/jachguate), ¿Qué pasó en el medio para que [Juan M](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m) fuera el gestor de comunidad y no jachguate?

¿Cómo es que se cambia el gestor finalmente?

- Comentario de jachguate: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6493/2012/11/22

> Hola, bienvenidos a la sala de chat de StackOverflow en Español. Por favor, si no has emitido aún tus votos sobre las preguntas de ejemplo, se te invita a hacerlo ahora, pues con los votos de 4 personas más lograremos pasar a la siguiente etapa!

- Primer saludo de [Juan M](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m): https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6493/2015/8/11

> Saludos a todos. Podemos empezar a platicar aquí sobre la estructura de nuestro nuevo sitio. Bienvenidos a nuestra charla :D

Además, como curiosidad, veo que el primer participante comprometido,  [Zero Piraeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1014938/zero-piraeus), ni siquiera tiene cuenta en *SOes*.

> Es la primera vez que me he comprometido a un sitio en Area 51 ... pero sí, ya cambió mi perfíl en SO.

¿Cómo fue elegido *Juan M* y por qué *jachguate* no fue moderador o gestor de comunidad?

Comment: A Juan M lo fichó la compañía a raíz del anuncio [Fluent in Spanish? We're hiring a Community Manager for a Spanish Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271998/1983854). Es decir, se fichó a alguien para cobrar de la empresa y gestionar lo que iba a ser SOes. jachguate y el resto de usuarios que propusieron el sitio son voluntarios que tuvieron su [importante] parte en la creación de la comunidad, pero como muchos otros al crear otras. La forma de crear sitios en Area51 era así: alguien propone, otros lo siguen y, tal vez, se llega a lanzar el sitio. Todo voluntario.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Es interesante, no sabía que Luiggi Mendoza todavía tiene una cuenta, solo fue eliminada de SOes, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1065197/luiggi-mendoza, En esa pregunta no aparece Juan M.

Comment: la pregunta real después de que Juan M fue fichado... quien fue el siguiente primer moderador???

Comment: no veo por que le cascan votos negativos a una pregunta en meta... cuando esta no es una mala pregunta ... conocer la historia del sitio no es algo que amerite estar en contra o en desacuerdo ... esto me parece que es una excelente pregunta ... para el museo de SOes.

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Si recuerdo bien fueron Luiggi Mendoza y Miquel Coll, tampoco supe cómo fueron elegidos.

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent todo esto lo tienes en [Histórico de moderadores de SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4395/83).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Veo que en ese historial no aparece el chat de Area 51. ¿Estaría bien ponerlo ahí?

Comment: Mmm ¿a qué chat te refieres? SOes como comunidad solamente ha tenido los moderadores allí listados (incluido tu anterior tú :P), pero el histórico de la comunidad en sí puede tener cosas que se me pasan por alto.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Me refería al chat que hablo en la pregunta... Que aparecía jachguate.

Comment: no es lo mismo fundadores que moderadores... separen los conceptos...

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Es verdad, pero al menos, si fue el fundador, me imagino que le la empresa le habrá propuesto y Jachguate se habrá negado a ser moderador, entonces empezaron a buscar a alguien más.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque necesita ser más específica  y sería más apropiada para Area 51 ya que trata más sobre lo que pasó en un caso particular del **proceso** de proponer/lanzar un nuevo sitio más que del funcionamiento dicho sitio, aún y cuando se trate de este sitio, empezando porque los links corresponden al chat de la propuesta en Area 51 y no al chat del Stack Overflow en español.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**¿Por qué jachguate no fue el gestor de la comunidad?**

*Resp:*
Por que el Gestor de la comunidad o CM fue escogido por la Empresa como Empleado.

**¿Cómo es que se cambia el gestor finalmente?**

*Resp:*
Un CM se cambia por que el actual Renuncia a su Cargo o por que el volumen de la comunidad es muy grande y no se da a basto...

**¿Cómo fue elegido Juan M y por qué jachguate no fue moderador o gestor de comunidad?**

*Resp:*
Antes de responder esta pregunta hay que aclarar que Gestor de comunidad (CM) no es lo mismo que Moderador en SE.

Normalmente el CM es un empleado de la empresa y en su cuenta aparece que forma parte del STAFF o es EMPLEADO y que regularmente tienen privilegios de Moderador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mientras que los Moderadores Diamantados: no forman parte de este staff y son electos por la comunidad at honoren:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces: he de interpretar que la empresa contrato directamente a Juan M como CM... y por otro lado jachguate imagino que no participo de las primeras elecciones de moderadores...